# Cannot upload sitemap from other domain in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, xml-sitemap, cdn

In the screenshot of Google Search Console below, I am looking at my property at `example.com/my-site`.

The black scribble is my site at `example.com/my-site`, and the yellow is me attempting to link my sitemap at `cdn-site.example/id/sitemap.xml`. Linking this sitemap through a shared `example.com/robots.txt` has not worked, probably because there is a relatively unrelated site at `example.com`.

Is it possible to "Add a new sitemap" with an external file, is there anything I'm missing here?

If not, can I set my sitemap to `.../my-site/sitemap.xml` in GSC and place a redirect (301) there to my CDN sitemap? Or will Googlebot be upset about the 301?

[image]

Comment: Could you host your full sitemap at `/my-site/sitemap.xml`?   External sitemaps are supposedly supported, but I've never seen anybody actually get them to work.

Comment: In my team the process for doing that is long, a redirect or GSC-centered fix would be much faster and more straightforward. And updating the sitemap build script to write to a local assets folder would also be complicated. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a server side redirect (301 I believe) at `/my-site/sitemap.xml` to `cdn-site.example/id/sitemap.xml`. Worked great!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue:

- My website is: `mywebsite.example.com`
- My sitemap and sitemap index files are generated and uploaded every night on `cdn.example.com/sitemap`

I couldn't add my sitemap index file `cdn.example.com/sitemap/sitemap.xml` in the Google Search Console tool.

So I added this in my website Nginx configuration:

```bash
# Nginx configuration for mywebsite.example.com
location /sitemap.xml {
    set $backend https://cdn.example.com/sitemap/sitemap.xml;
    proxy_pass $backend;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

To get my sitemap index file accessible on `mywebsite.example.com/sitemap.xml`. I didn't redirect the sitemap files (because I want to keep it simple and don't use rewrite rules if I can), so only my sitemap index is accessible on my website domain. My sitemap index file looks like this:

```html
<!-- mywebsite.example.com/sitemap.xml -->
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://cdn.example.com/sitemap/sitemap-item-1.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-02-24</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <!-- ... -->
</sitemapindex>
```

It seems to work in the Search Console: my URLs were discovered. But I don't see the sitemap files in the UI, probably because of the different domain.
I sent a comment to Google with a screenshot, I'll post an update if I get a response.

[image: Google Search Console - sitemap index with sitemaps on another domain]

---

**TLDR**: If you use a sitemap index file, it **seems** that you don't need to add your sitemap files in your website domain, only the sitemap index file.

---

**Edit 2023-04-04** This does not work anymore, I have an error now in the search console.

[Now the documentation says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451001#error_list&zippy=%2Cerror-list):

> Your sitemap includes some URLs that are at a higher level or different domain than the sitemap file.
>
> Different domain: Check that the URLs all begin with the same domain as your sitemap location.